# Count for object key label

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a defined object, among other fields, with an integer identifier:

```
class Car:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.model = "Ford"
        self.id = None

    def setId (self, id):
        self.id = id
```

In a list containing several of these objects, I would like to be able to count how many of these objects are repeated and in what quantity each of them, but only looking at the ID number (which in this case can be repeated).
I would like to know if there is a similar way to the method to order, to which you can pass a key and with which it is easy to order:

```
def keySort(car):
    return car.id

hand.sort(key=keySort)
```

I would like something like:

```
ID 22313 : repeated 2 times
ID 98 : repeated 14 times
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`, e.g.:

```
from collections import Counter

for car_id, count in Counter(car.id for car in cars):
    print(f"ID {car_id} : repeated {count} times")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(obj.id for obj in all_objects)
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you.